# Redirecting after Ajax post

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want the success on ajax post to go to the home page. For some reason I keep doing it wrong. Any idea what I should do to fix this?

```
window.APP_ROOT_URL = "<%= root_url %>";
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({ url: '#{addbank_bankaccts_path}',
 type: 'POST',
 beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '#{form_authenticity_token}')},
 dataType: "json",
 data: 'some_uri=' + response.data.uri ,
 success: function(APP_ROOT_URL) {
      window.location.assign(APP_ROOT_URL);
  }
});
```

Comment: are you sure the ajax is returning with a success?

Comment: `window.location.href = APP_ROOT_URL`

Comment: Do you see any messages in the browser's console?

Comment: @abc123 has the right answer as well - but first i would confirm that you are actually getting a successful return. check the console and network.

Comment: i get this from firebug post response window.location.href = http://localhost:3000/

Comment: @AlainGoldman, in firebug console type APP_ROOT_URL to make sure its set.  In your success handler, put an alert.  Add a fail handler, also with an alert.  What is the exact response from the server?

Comment: APP_ROOT_URL works in the console but your right i dont think i'm getting a success because i just put an alert in there.

Comment: @AlainGoldman, do you have a live page we can see?  Are there any errors in the console?  Is `response` defined before your AJAX function is called?  Do you mean to override APP_ROOT_URL in your success handler?

Comment: no live page cause it's in a rails app but there are no errors in the console. response is defined before the AJAX function is called. No in the success i just want to make it to the root_url

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
success: function(response){
    window.location.href = response.redirect;
}
```

Hope the above will help because I had the same problem

Comment: (-1) because `assign` is valid, and there was no indication of the  JSON format (e.g. the redirect property).

Answer (score 13):

You can return the JSON from server with redirect status and redirect URL.

```
{"redirect":true,"redirect_url":"https://example.com/go/to/somewhere.html"}
```

And in your jQuery ajax handler

```js
success: function (res) {
    // check redirect
    if (res.redirect) {
        window.location.href = res.redirect_url;
    }
}
```

Note you must set `dataType: 'json'` in ajax config. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why, but `window.location.href` did not work for me. I ended up using `window.location.replace` instead, which actually worked.

```
$('#checkout').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax('/post/url', {
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data.cartCount === 0) {
            alert('There are no items in cart to checkout');
        }
        else {
            window.location.replace('/Checkout/AddressAndPayment');
        }
    });
});
```