# jquery form submit not working before redirect

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to submit a form after the saved button of a jquery modal dialog is pressed, then redirect user to another window.
The problem is, the form submission doesn't work with the redirect, but only works without.

I'm new to jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
var currentForm = $("#confirm").closest('form');

$("#menu a").on('click', function(e){      
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hasChanged){
        e.preventDefault();
        var message = "Save changes?"
        $('#confirm').modal({
            closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
            position: ["20%",],
            overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
            containerId: 'confirm-container', 
            onShow: function (dialog) {
                $('.message', dialog.data[0]).append(message);

                $('.quit', dialog.data[0]).click(function () { 
                    hasChanged = false;
                    window.location.href = targetUrl;
                    $.modal.close();
                }),
                $('.cancel', dialog.data[0]).click(function () { 
                    $.modal.close();
                }),
                $('.save', dialog.data[0]).click(function () {
                    hasChanged = false;
                    currentForm.submit();
                    $.modal.close();
                    window.location.href = targetUrl;//form submit works only when this line is commented
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You can not submit a form _and_ redirect somewhere else at the same time. Either submit your form data via AJAX in the background, and then redirect when the response for that request comes in, or have your script that processes the form values do the redirect afterwards.

Comment: Provide your html also

Comment: use AJAX, for more info, [follow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118627/redirecting-after-ajax-post/18118675)

Comment: Thanks for reply. didn't know that. so i'll use ajax. :)