# Have url redirection after ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, url, redirect

I am using the following php code along with ajax. Everything works fine, but instead of only prompting with an ajax confirmation message that the message has gone through, i would like a url redirection. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php   
// Check if sent
try {
    $sendmailResult = mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $headers);
    if( $sendmailResult === TRUE ) {
            returnAndExitAjaxResponse(

            constructAjaxResponseArray(
            TRUE
            )

        );


    } else {
        returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
            constructAjaxResponseArray(
                FALSE,
                'ERROR_AT_PHPMAIL',
                array('error_information'=> error_get_last() )
            )
        );
    }
} catch (Exception $_e) {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            TRUE,
            'ERROR_AT_PHPMAIL',
            array('error_message'=> $_e->getMessage())
        )
    );
}

/*
    Construct ajax response array
    Input: Result (bool), Message (optional), Data to be sent back in array
*/
function constructAjaxResponseArray ($_response, $_message = '', $_json = null) {
    $_responseArray = array();
    $_response = ( $_response === TRUE ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    $_responseArray['response'] = $_response;
    if(isset($_message)) $_responseArray['message'] = $_message;
    if(isset($_json)) $_responseArray['json'] = $_json;
    return $_responseArray;
}
/*
    Returns in the Gframe ajax format.
    Input: data array processed by constructAjaxResponseArray ()
    Outputs as a html stream then exits.
*/
function returnAndExitAjaxResponse ($_ajaxResponse) {
    if(!$_ajaxResponse){
        $_ajaxResponse = array('response'=>false,'message'=>'Unknown error occurred.');
    }
     header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($_ajaxResponse);
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the ajax code you are using ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage or if you fancy PHP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting after Ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118627/redirecting-after-ajax-post)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is ajax, I don't think you can redirect it directly from the backend call.

The best solution that I can think for this (of course there maybe other solutions that I am unaware but just giving you my insights) is return the url that you want to redirect to in the AJAX response and then use `document.location.href` for redirection from javascript when your AJAX call is successfull.

Hope this helps.