# Redirect from an AJAX Post

Tags: ajax, redirect

I have an AJAX call to my endpoint in my Spring controller.  After verifying the info from the POST, my controller makes a redirect decision, whether to forward the request to the next location, or send them back to a login page.  The response to the post is correct, it's a 302 with the `Location` header set correctly.  However, when the page makes the redirect call, it makes an OPTIONS call to the URL, then a GET call, which just returns the HTML.  Great, I have the HTML, but the page stays on my JSP page and never goes to the external URL.  How do I manage this?

Sample Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/token/{token_code}", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public void validateToken(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse, @PathVariable String token_code) {
  //set some servlet request attributes from incoming packet info
  if(isTokenValid(token_code)) {
       servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(MyConstants.JSP_DEVICE_INFO).forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
   }
  else {
     servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(MyConstants.FAILURE_URL).forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
  }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/token/tokenRedirect", method = {RequestMethod.POST},headers = "content-type=application/json",consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ModelAndView getSession(HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                                   HttpServletResponse servletResponse,
                                   @RequestBody TokenValidateRequest request)
{
  boolean isValid = verifyCollectedInfo(request);
  if(isValid) {
      servletResponse.setHeader("Location", request.url());
      servletResponse.setStatus(302);

  }
  else {
      servletResponse.setHeader("Location", MyConstants.FAILURE_URL);
      servletResponse.setStatus(302);
  }
}
```

JSP Ajax call:

```
   $.ajax({
         headers: {
             'accept': 'application/json',
             'content-type': 'application/json'
         },
         type: "POST",
         url: "tokenRedirect",
         context:document.body,
         contentType:"application/json",
         data:JSON.stringify(TokenValidateObject)

     });
```

So when I inspect my network traffic, I see the 302 status is set for the response and the Location header has the URL I want, but it just fetches the HTML for the redirect URL, it doesn't actually switch views

Comment: What does you code look like?

Comment: @Rust I'll post it from a previous question, give me one second

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the front end to redirect instead of the back-end. Ajax is meant to make a asynchronous request which then can be consumed on the front end.

So, instead of redirecting in the back end, just tell it `print` the redirect location and redirect using the returned data on the front end.

```
$.ajax({
     headers: {
         'accept': 'application/json',
         'content-type': 'application/json'
     },
     type: "POST",
     url: "tokenRedirect",
     context:document.body,
     contentType:"application/json",
     data:JSON.stringify(TokenValidateObject)
     success: function(locationToRedirect){
         window.location = locationToRedirect
     } 
});
```

Comment: So on my controller, would I change the return to a String and just read it there?  I'm also setting cookies along the redirect domain, would those be retained in this redirect action?

Comment: @user3334871 No, ajax is contained. You could print the cookies and location as an JSON object string and then set the cookies using Javascript and do the redirect

Comment: So just to make sure I understand it correctly, in my Spring controller I set the cookie in the servletResponse, but that won't carry over on the AJAX redirect call, I'll have to return it in a JSON object like I do my redirect URL and set it in the callback function?

Comment: @user3334871 Yep, you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using XHR, the client-side code needs to read the HTTP response and handle the redirect using JavaScript. The browser will only execute the redirect for a PAGE, not an XHR call.

See: [Redirecting after Ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118627/redirecting-after-ajax-post/18118675)

[How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

[Redirect on Ajax Jquery Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927044/redirect-on-ajax-jquery-call/2927305)

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: Does `response.redirect` contain the Location URL? Is it set from that header when a 302 response comes in?