# How do I call a controller action from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Why the `Confirm` view is not loaded after this successful `ajax` call? I can see the *"success"* alert,
step into the controller action code (in debug mode) and see the correct `id` value.

```
        // send nonce and verification data to your server

        var nonce = payload.nonce;

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/store/confirm/',
            data: { id: nonce },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
```

Controller action successfully called:

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Confirm(string id)
    {
        return View(); // this view never display on browser!
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect from an AJAX Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928002/redirect-from-an-ajax-post)

Comment: your url is calling `payment`, your controller action is `Confirm`

Comment: @Hooman: my mistake, I've updated the question.

Comment: @Yinqiu: it does not compile...

Comment: Hi @abenci,how about return json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

```
public ActionResult Confirm()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirm(string id)
{
    return Json(new { redirectToUrl = "/store/Confirm" });
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/store/confirm/',
        data: { id: nonce },
        success: function (response) {
            window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the following error: _JsonResult does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument._